# Why is this dropdown menu being overlapped

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have created a CSS dropdown menu, but when it drops down, it is being overlapped by the content, and renders useless.

How do i fix this?

Code

QUESTION SOLVED...THANKS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the z-index of the drop down menu
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 2):

Set your [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of your nav higher than your content and the problem will go away. For z-index to work properly in all browsers the element with the z-index on it much also have a position:relative or position:absolute.

### Update

```
ul.dropdown { position: relative;  border-radius:10px; z-index:9999}
#content{position:relative; z-index:100} /* #content should be whatever your content div is */
```

Comment: can u please explain by re pasting the code with the correction. Thanks'